# jQuery find select where value equals

Tags: jquery

I am building an invoicing system and I use clone on the line item rows so I have multiple select boxes that share the same class `invoice_line_item` and each one has a unique ID.  The problem is I won't always have access to the ID to target it.

Im looking for a way to search all the selects with the class of invoice_line_item to find the one thats selected option value is set to `new` so I can change its selected value and fire the change event.

I have tried

```
if($('select.invoice_line_item').val() === 'new'){
   $(this).val(data.hashId).change();
}
```

and I know a little about `.find()` but I dont know if that would help me here?

Comment: Wouldnt that mean `.select` would be the class?  As I understand it using `select.invoice_line_item` will look for each select box with the class of `select invoice_line_item`.  The way you describe it, as I understand it means it would need to be `<select class="select invoice_line_item">` and that is not how I have it, I just use the `invoice_line_item` class

Comment: yes sry mis read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use jQuery `.each` to iterate through your elements and manually filter those which have `value === new`:

```
$('select.invoice_line_item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "new") {
        $(this).val(data.hashId).change();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter()` or `each`. Your approach does not deal with individual instances

```
$('select.invoice_line_item').filter(function(){
   return this.value === 'new';
}).val(data.hashId).change();
```